# Setting up Kyoto Cabinet in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, installation, kyotocabinet

I am trying to setup Kyoto Cabinet in Visual Studio (VC++).  I added the source files and the static library kyotocabinet.lib

However, it is giving me a link error LINK2005
By default, the library is built with linking to `LIBCMT.LIB' by the`/MT' option. I also tried rebuilding the library with the `/MD' option. I am still unable to do it.

Has someone tried to use it in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.
We just have to create a new empty C++ project in Visual Studio.
Add the header files and the static library from [Kyoto Cabinet Win32 Package](http://fallabs.com/kyotocabinet/winpkg/)

Set the Runtime Library from Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Code Generation to [/MT]